# Can't run meteor 1.2 in macbook 2016

Tags: meteor

When I run the meteor command I get the following error:

[image]

this happens after it tries to `Downloading meteor-tool@1.1.11-faster...` then crashes.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you require ver. 1.2? The latest as today is 1.4.

Comment: @kometen yes, this app would require a lot of time to upgrade to the latest version, as of now it has been decided to just use 1.2. Also, I've tried to run another project which is version 1.3 and still gave me the same error.

Comment: I see, have been there myself some years ago. Have you tried to run the command using sudo?

Comment: I tried just now and gave me the same error :(

Comment: Well, don't know what happen but I installed node version 0.10.40 and it worked after that.

Comment: Sound good, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those having similar issues I solved it by installing nvm and using node version 0.10.40 and then running `meteor` inside the project and it worked.

**EDIT**

I was having issues with 1.3 as well after doing this so I did the following to get it running:

I was able to get it running by doing `https://install.meteor.com/?release=1.3.2.4 | sh` and now everything seems to work even the 1.2 and 1.3, haven't tested 1.4 yet but hopefully it works.